# Is there a standard way of defining the href that opens in a document.open call?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, jquery-bbq

The dilemma that I'm dealing with is that in the [jquery-bbq code](https://raw.github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq/v1.2.1/jquery.ba-bbq.js), because IE6 and IE7 do not support `hashchange`, they load pages twice in order to have a history state.

This has a negative effect because code runs twice on both server-side and client-side. The method used to create the iframe is this:

```
  if ( is_old_ie ) {

    // Create hidden IFRAME at the end of the body.
    iframe = $('<iframe src="javascript:0"/>').hide().appendTo( 'body' )[0].contentWindow;

    // Get history by looking at the hidden IFRAME's location.hash.
    get_history = function() {
      return get_fragment( iframe.document.location.href );
    };

    // Set a new history item by opening and then closing the IFRAME
    // document, *then* setting its location.hash.
    set_history = function( hash, history_hash ) {
      if ( hash !== history_hash ) {
        var doc = iframe.document;
        doc.open().close();
        doc.location.hash = '#' + hash;
      }
    };

    // Set initial history.
    set_history( get_fragment() );
  }
```

A blank iframe with a src of `javascript:0` is created. The `document.open` method is called, and it seems like it grabs the `location.href` of the parent window as the default for the page that opens with `.open`.

I basically have to modify the code so that it doesn't open the same url twice, so I'm looking to override the default and specify a param such as ?iframe=true.

Example:

http://example.com/views/step-2?one=two

In IE, the page above gets loaded and then gets loaded again in an iframe. The server-side code executes **twice**, but I don't want that to happen.

I want to append `&iframe=1` to the URI so I can prevent my server-side code from running if the `iframe` param is specified.

The two most obvious things are:

1. Set the src of the iframe, but this could have a negative effect and I'm pretty sure it's there for a reason.
2. Instead of use `document.open.close`, use `iframe.location.href` and set it to the href manually.

If anyone has had experience with iframe hacking, I'd greatly appreciate some tips.

**EDIT**: Another workaround I thought of would be loading a page through iframe/ajax that sets a session var before the iframe does the `document.open`, which creates a session variable of 'iframeloading' which is equal to 1, and set a load event handler on iframe load to set it back to 0, and adjust my server-side code to not execute if the session var is set to 1. Something like:

```
$('<iframe src="/iframe-loading.php"/>').hide().appendTo('body');
document.open().close()
 $( document.defaultView ).load(function() {
    $('<iframe src="iframe-doneloading.php/>').hide().appendTo('body');
});
```

Comment: if i give you an alternative way to handle hashchange event with jquery it colud slove your problems?

Comment: If you could fix the hashchange loading twice problem, it would save you a lot of time. The jQuery BBQ documentation mentions: "Be sure to bind to the "hashchange" event on document.ready, not before, or else it may fail in IE6/7." That's not your problem, is it? Also, you could post your issue to the project GitHub page at https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq/issues

Answer (score 1):

About "Is there a standard way of defining the href that opens in a document.open call?"

No, there is not.